# Is $x^2 + 1$ irreducible polynomial in $\Bbb R[x,y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Is $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible polynomial in $\Bbb R[x,y]$?

Actually I recently got to know that $\Bbb R[x,y] \over \langle x^2 +1\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R[i][y]$ which is a PID not a field. So $x^2 + 1$  is certainly not irreducible.

Can anyone please help me to find two polynomial in $\Bbb R[x,y]$  whose multiplication is $x^2 + 1$?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb R$? It is not a field but it is an integral domain, so $x^2+1$ is irreducible.

Comment: Is $R$ any ring, or do you mean again $R=\Bbb{R}$? If yes, then you should start considering to write $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: yes the set of all real numbers,

Comment: @INDIAN Then *at least* explicitly write that down, or better: writte \Bbb R  for the symbol of real numbers

Comment: And you seem to insist in trying to project things that are true in $\;\Bbb R[x]\;$ into $\;\Bbb R[x,y]\;$ ...

Comment: Edited@DonAntonio

Comment: Maybe unknowingly. But I am on the verge of understanding the previous problem . @DonAntonio

Comment: @INDIAN Way to go, honest. I believe you will finally understand this piece of theory, yet one thing must already be clear: the rings $\;\Bbb R[x]\;,\;\;\Bbb R[x,y]\;$ are pretty different in several important ways. Do not try to project properties from one unto the other one as these may fail.

Comment: Please: Proper notation is $\displaystyle {\Bbb R[x,y] \over \langle x^2 +1\rangle},$ not $\displaystyle {\Bbb R[x,y] \over <x^2 +1>.} \qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\;x^2+1\;$ indeed is irreducible in $\;\Bbb R[x,y]\;$ , yet the ideal $\;\langle x^2+1\rangle\;$ is *not* maximal in that ring since, for example

$$\langle x^2+1\rangle\lneq\langle x^2+1\,,\,\,y\rangle\le\Bbb R[x,y]$$

Thus, the quotient ring can't indeed be a field...

Answer (score 2):

The quotient ${\Bbb R}[x,y]/\langle x^2+1\rangle \cong {\Bbb C}[y]$ is a domain (but not a field). So the ideal $\langle x^2+1 \rangle$ is prime (but not maximal) and $x^2 + 1$ *is* irreducible.